# Asp:Button inside in asp:Panel not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

Button inside asp:Panel is not firing.
Code is below;

```
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlMainBoxProfilProfil" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" >
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfilSoyadi" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Button Text="Kaydet" runat="server" ID="btnProfilGuncelle" OnClick="btnProfilGuncelle_Click" />
      </asp:Panel>
```

Please help me. I got stuck in it.

Comment: Well is the panel disabled, with the information you have provided this is going to be a guess game (Can you edit the TextBox ?)

Comment: Are you using `autoeventwireup` and can you show us the code in your `btnProfilGuncelle_Click` method.

Comment: Yes. `autoeventwireup` is set true and I have `btnProfilGuncelle_Click` method in code-behind.

Comment: Does the  button cause a postback at all? I mean is `Page_Load` hit whereas the click-handler not?

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but try: </asp:Button> instead of />

Comment: No postback. Button does nothing when I clicked.

Comment: @Pavenhimself I tried. No change.

Comment: can you paste your codebehind?

Comment: I checked with some dump code and its working.

Comment: Ok I solved by adding `onclientclick="_dosPostBack(this,'');"` thanks for your replies :)

Comment: why do you need that? i just checked your code and included some code on code-behind and it worked.

Comment: I used lots of JQuery that set Panel is visible or not visible. So I think a confliction occured when using JQuery

Comment: JQery and ASP.NET will never be friends.

Comment: your jquery is hindering the post request of button.